# numpy change elements matching conditions

Tags: numpy

For two numpy array a, b

```
a=[1,2,3]      b=[4,5,6]
```

I want to change x<2.5 data of a to b. So I tried

```
a[a<2.5]=b
```

hoping a to be `a=[4,5,3]`. 
but this makes error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    a[a<2.5]=b
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 2 output values where the mask is true
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is a result of how masks work on numpy arrays.

When you write

```
a[a < 2.5]
```

you get back the elements of `a` which match the mask `a < 2.5`.  In this case, that will be the first two elements only.

Attempting to do

```
a[a < 2.5] = b
```

is an error because `b` has three elements, but `a[a < 2.5]` has only two.

---

An easy way to achieve the result you're after in numpy is to use `np.where`.

The syntax of this is `np.where(condition, valuesWhereTrue, valuesWhereFalse)`.

In your case, you could write

```
newArray = np.where(a < 2.5, b, a)
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want the overhead of a new array, you could perform the replacement in-place (as you're trying to do in the question).  To achieve this, you can write:

```
idxs = a < 2.5
a[idxs] = b[idxs]
```